# How to correctly format the if statement for ie (lte 8 before another script) on sublime text 3 or really in any editor

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, sublimetext3

Today I have a problem that I guess any newby bump up before or later in their career when they have to declare a conditional script to make something work on Internet Explorer.

Here's my code:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//somescript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//anotherscript.js"></script>
<script> function anyscript() {} </script>
```

Essentially, I order to my browser to run a script if the version of internet explorer is older than 8 or, in the case that is more recent, to run another script.

So far so good, but the problem is that on sublime 3 or I guess in any other text editor, that small snippet will mess up with the order of the code, and it will force to indent the code so that it will miss a tab.

Essentially, on your sheet right after that snippet, you won't be able to close the next tag so the entire code will become messy (depend on when you insert that, of course).

I was wondering if it is possible to write that snippet in a different way, so your editor will recognize it and it will indent your code like it supposes to do.

Comment: I actually find a solution: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248025/indentation-error-with-sublime-text